# Docker container cannot be accessed from localhost despite both --network host and expose ports are set

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My system is composed of two parts: a Postgres local_db, and a Nodejs express server that communicates with it via [prisma ORM](https://www.prisma.io/). The Nodejs server, whenever receives a GET request to `localhost:4000/`, shall reply with a 200-code message as shown in the code:

```
app.get("/", (_req, res) => res.send("Hello!"))
```

Basically, this behavior is used further in a health check.

The database is instantiated by the `docker-compose.yml` (I omit parts not related to networking):

```
services:
  timescaledb: 
    image: timescale/timescaledb:2.8.1-pg14
    container_name: timescale-db
    ports:
      - "5000:5432"
```

And a Nodejs backend run in a container, whose Dockerfile is (omitting the parts related to Nodejs building):

```
FROM node:18

# Declare and set environment variables
ENV TIMESCALE_DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5000/postgres?connect_timeout=300"

# Build app
RUN npm run build

# Expose the listening port
EXPOSE 4000

# Run container as non-root (unprivileged) user
# The node user is provided in the Node.js base image
USER node
CMD npx prisma migrate deploy; node ./build/main.js
```

The container is made to run via:

```
docker run -it --network host --name backend my-backend-image
```

However, despite the container actually finding and successfully connecting to the database (thus populating it), I cannot access to `localhost:4000` from the host machine as it tells me connection refused. Furthermore, using `curl` I obtain the same reply:

```
$ curl -f http://localhost:4000                                                                                                                                                         
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4000: Connection refused
```

I have even tried to connect to the localhost actual ip `127.0.0.1:4000` but still refuses the connection, or to the actual docker daemon address `http://172.17.0.1:4000` but the connection keeps hanging.

I do not understand why I cannot access it, even though I have set the flag `--network host` when running the container, that should map one-to-one the ports of my host machine.

Comment: What is your host OS?  Host networking just doesn't work on MacOS or Windows, and for the setup you describe it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: My host OS is Windows 10 together with WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04LTS). All the commands that I shared above are sent using the Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: When running `docker container ls -a` what is the output for the `PORTS` for your container? As @DavidMaze mentions, the host networking driver only works on Linux hosts (https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/). Run your container through `docker run -p 4000:4000 --name backend my-backend-image` (https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-expose-in-dockerfile-266938b6a33d).

Comment: For the container named "backend" the output of PORTS is none, whereas for timescale-db is `0.0.0.0:5000->5432/tcp`.  I have already tried without `network=host` and by mapping `-p 4000:4000`, but in that case it cannot connect to the database anymore.
(i.e., Unable to connect to the database: PrismaClientInitializationError: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5000`)

Comment: That's expected, normally each container is its own `localhost`.

Comment: Indeed. This is why I wanted to use `--network host`, but it looks like Windows does not allow it. I'll create a network from scratch, and finally, make them communicate if it's the only way to make it working.

Comment: When you include both the service for your backend and your database in your `docker-compose.yml` file, they will share the same network.